# Create nested Json in js

Tags: javascript, json

I want to create Json like this:

```
{
    "name":"name",
    "children":[
        {
            "childName":"name"
        },
        {
            "childName":"name"
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't know how to place none-named property in json obj and place and obj into "children".

Comment: you should refer the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10485014/create-a-nested-json-object-dynamically

Comment: can you please be more clear?

Comment: @yashhy Krishna have solved it.Thanks any way.

Comment: @zzy okay.. http://jsfiddle.net/yashhy/3T3cf/ refer this. This is what I was trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, if you mean key itself is variable then you cannot create json-object in single shot, 
you will have to create it using '[]' notation

```
var myObj = {}; 
myObj[myProp1] = [] //or some value or some json/map again
myObj[myProp2] = 'hi'
```

myProp1 and myProp2 are variables.if you can explain your problem in more detail then you will get more clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you ask how to manipulate that JSON object, then maybe this would help.

Your original object:

```
var object = {
        "name":"name",
        "children":[
            {
                "childName":"name"
            },
            {
                "childName":"name"
            }
        ]
    };
```

1) How to place none-named property in json obj.

Object is not array, so should assign key/value, though either or both of them were empty. You can insert using dot or like array assignment.

```
object.country = "Malaysia";
object[""] = "No Keys";
object["novalue"] = "";
```

2) How to place an obj into "children".

```
var aNewChild = {
    "childName": "Handsome one"
};

object.children.push(aNewChild);
```